# android - listview losing the rows of data when hitting back button

Tags: java, android, listview

Please give me a hand with an issue I am having with a ListView and its related data in my android development project.

I have an activity called OrderForm that gets started by an Intent from the activity UserProfile as such:

**In UserProfile**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderForm.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Then in OrderForm there is an EditText and an add button to add String items to an ArrayList, and the UI gets populated accordingly.

When I click the back button (back to UserProfile) and go via the Intent to OrderForm again, the UI does not show the list items, why is that?

I realize I can use Room for persistence and even SharedPreferences, but
I wanted to see if there is cleaner, more efficient method, otherwise the less code the better.

Also, maybe I'm not understanding them correctly, but I tried onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState and they don't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Here is part of the code from **OrderForm**

```
public class OrderForm extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> list;
ListView itemList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_form);

    itemList = findViewById(R.id.itemList);

    itemText = findViewById(R.id.item);
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.no_items_container);
    orderContainer = findViewById(R.id.orderContainer);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item,R.id.rowItem, list)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position,
                            View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
          // some custom stuff here
        }
    }

public void addItem(View view)
{
    String item = itemText.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

    if(!item.isEmpty() && list.indexOf(item) == -1) {
        arrayAdapter.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are losing your reference to the ArrayList that you put the items into... you need to show more code. Specifically, your array adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how Activity lifecycles work.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Your issue is that when pressing the back button, your OrderForm Activity is destroyed and effectively your arraylist/list view is destroyed. To avoid this problem, you'll have to store the values somewhere for example SharedPreferences, create a text file holding your strings and store it, or return the arraylist back to the UserProfile class where you'll store/handle them (to do that use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity())

Comment: Sure, I could use SharedPreferences but for me it is not intuitive. Correct me if I'm astray, but this mechanism stores, as the name suggests, Preference Data, not user data.

Comment: @MichaelTheodore don't worry about only storing "preferences" inside SharedPreferences; it's a lightweight way to save any sort of key-value data.

Answer (score 0):

> When I click the back button (back to UserProfile) and go via the Intent to OrderForm again, the UI does not show the list items, why is that?

In your `onCreate()` method, you have this:

```
list = new ArrayList<>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(..., list)...
```

Unless you persist your data in some way, `list` is always going to be empty when your activity starts up.

> I realize I can use Room for persistence and even SharedPreferences, but I wanted to see if there is cleaner, more efficient method, otherwise the less code the better.

Exactly what you need to store will help define the best way to store it. For a simple list of strings, probably SharedPreferences is the simplest solution.

> Also, maybe I'm not understanding them correctly, but I tried onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState and they don't work for me.

These methods are used to store data when an activity is *destroyed and then recreated*, which commonly happens when the user rotates the device (but can also happen for various other reasons). When you *exit* your activity (by pressing `back` to UserProfile), these methods aren't triggered.